# Android SQLite Added Extra Columns now can't view data

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I had this previously working with only two of the parameters, 'Weight' and Waist', I then proceeded to add extra columns to the database, resulting in the application force closing when I try to view the data.

I thought perhaps this was due to their already being data in the database, so I completely reinstalled the app (I'm testing this on my own device) and it still isn't working.

Below is the class that handles all the SQL:

```
public class Stats {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";
    public static final String KEY_WAIST = "waist";
    public static final String KEY_CHEST = "chest";
    public static final String KEY_LEGS = "legs";
    public static final String KEY_ARMS = "arms";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "statsDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "personalStats";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ffHelper;
    private final Context ffContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ffDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_WEIGHT
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_WAIST + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + KEY_CHEST + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_LEGS
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_ARMS + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }




    public Stats(Context c) {
        ffContext = c;
    }

    public Stats open() throws SQLException {
        ffHelper = new DbHelper(ffContext);
        ffDatabase = ffHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void close() {
        ffHelper.close();

    }

    public long createEntry(String weight, String waist, String chest, String legs, String arms) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_WEIGHT, weight);
        cv.put(KEY_WAIST, waist);
        cv.put(KEY_CHEST, chest);
        cv.put(KEY_LEGS, legs);
        cv.put(KEY_ARMS, arms);
        return ffDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_WAIST, KEY_CHEST, KEY_LEGS, KEY_ARMS };
        Cursor c = ffDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iWeight = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEIGHT);
        int iWaist = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WAIST);
        int iChest = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHEST);
        int iLegs = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LEGS);
        int iArms = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ARMS);
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iWeight)
                    + " " + c.getString(iWaist) 
                    + " " + c.getString(iChest) 
                    + " " + c.getString(iLegs) 
                    + " " + c.getString(iArms) + "\n";

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Below is my logcat:

```
 I/ActivityManager( 1294): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.uhi.fatfighter/.Splash u=0} from pid 1567
    D/PermissionCache(  630): checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=1000 => granted (1098 us)
    D/dalvikvm( 2733): Late-enabling CheckJNI
    I/ActivityManager( 1294): Start proc com.uhi.fatfighter for activity com.uhi.fatfighter/.Splash: pid=2733 uid=10072 gids={3003, 1015, 1028}
    D/dalvikvm( 1294): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 764K, 26% free 7870K/10567K, paused 78ms, total 83ms
    I/dalvikvm-heap( 1294): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.014MB for 1048592-byte allocation
    E/Trace   ( 2733): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    D/libEGL  ( 2733): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
    D/libEGL  ( 2733): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
    D/libEGL  ( 2733): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
    D/OpenGLRenderer( 2733): Enabling debug mode 0
    I/ActivityManager( 1294): Displayed com.uhi.fatfighter/.Splash: +980ms
    D/dalvikvm( 1845): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1484K, 26% free 7796K/10439K, paused 19ms+6ms, total 95ms
    D/dalvikvm( 1845): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 76ms
    D/AudioHardware(  633): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
    V/AudioHardware(  633): closeMixer_l() mMixerOpenCnt: 1
    D/AudioHardware(  633): closePcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 1
    D/dalvikvm( 1457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1820K, 71% free 2483K/8451K, paused 23ms+6ms, total 63ms
    I/ActivityManager( 1294): START {act=com.uhi.fatfighter.MainActivity cmp=com.uhi.fatfighter/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 2733
    I/ActivityManager( 1294): Displayed com.uhi.fatfighter/.MainActivity: +625ms
    D/AudioHardware(  633): AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
    V/AudioHardware(  633): open pcm_out driver
    D/AudioHardware(  633): openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
    V/AudioHardware(  633): openMixer_l() mMixerOpenCnt: 0
    V/AudioHardware(  633): open playback normal
    V/AudioHardware(  633): write() wakeup setting route SPK
    I/ActivityManager( 1294): START {act=com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView cmp=com.uhi.fatfighter/.DBView u=0} from pid 2733
    D/AndroidRuntime( 2733): Shutting down VM
    W/dalvikvm( 2733): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41196300)
    D/dalvikvm( 1294): GC_CONCURRENT freed 849K, 28% free 8860K/12167K, paused 19ms+12ms, total 184ms
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4928)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:747)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView.onCreate(DBView.java:15)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 2733):    ... 11 more
    W/ActivityManager( 1294):   Force finishing activity com.uhi.fatfighter/.DBView
    W/ActivityManager( 1294):   Force finishing activity com.uhi.fatfighter/.MainActivity
    D/dalvikvm( 1294): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1194K, 37% free 7765K/12167K, paused 68ms, total 68ms
    W/ActivityManager( 1294): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{417c3b50 com.uhi.fatfighter/.DBView}
    I/Process ( 2733): Sending signal. PID: 2733 SIG: 9
    I/WindowState( 1294): WIN DEATH: Window{415b12d0 com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.MainActivity paused=true}
    I/ActivityManager( 1294): Process com.uhi.fatfighter (pid 2733) has died.
    W/InputDispatcher( 1294): channel '4158f330 com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.Splash (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
    E/InputDispatcher( 1294): channel '4158f330 com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.Splash (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    W/InputDispatcher( 1294): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4158f330 com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.Splash (server)'
    I/WindowState( 1294): WIN DEATH: Window{4158f330 com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.Splash paused=false}
    W/ActivityManager( 1294): Force removing ActivityRecord{41631c20 com.uhi.fatfighter/.Splash}: app died, no saved state
    I/WindowManager( 1294): WINDOW DIED Window{4158f330 com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.Splash paused=false}
    W/InputMethodManagerService( 1294): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2733 uid 10072
```

Below is the code for DBView.java:

```
public class DBView extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_stats);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDBInfo);
        Stats dbInfo = new Stats(this);
        dbInfo.open();
        String data = dbInfo.getData();
        dbInfo.close();
        tv.setText(data);


    }



}
```

Below is the code for view_stats.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Weight" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Waist" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Chest" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Legs" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Arms" />
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDBInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="info from db" />
    </TableLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: if you want to add new column just update your table in onUpgrade()...with update query

Comment: Post logcat content for better claity

Comment: You didn't update `DATABASE_VERSION`, did you?

Comment: I have tested your code and everything seems alright. You should uninstall the app and again give a try..

Comment: I have added my logcat, it was quite large so I cut the bits that din't contain my app name

Comment: @CobraAjgar I'm more lookng to recreating the DB from scratch, I made the mistake of only originally implementing it with 2 fields, when in reality it needs 5

Comment: @CRUSADER i have posted my logcat ^^

Comment: @CL I have changed the DATABASE_VERSION to 2, still not working...

Comment: The problem seems to be in ComponentInfo. Post the code of ComponentInfo activity for  better answer.

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe I'm not sure how to do that? is this inside logcat? should I post full logcat?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Post code for DBView. The activity that gets launched after MainActivity.

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe I have added the code for the DBView class

Comment: Which one is line 15 in your DBView activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:
You are not making any entries to the database.
Make sure that "tvDBInfo" is a text view. If it is text view then only post the code for "view_stats".

I tried the following code and it is working :

```
public class DBView extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_stats);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDBInfo);
        Stats dbInfo = new Stats(this);
        dbInfo.open();
        dbInfo.createEntry("weight", "waist", "chest", "legs", "arms");
        String data = dbInfo.getData();
        dbInfo.close();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
            tv.setText(data);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with your layout. You have nested text view within a text view which is not feasible. Change the last three text view inside the table row i.e

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Chest" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Legs" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Arms" />
</TextView>
```

to this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Chest" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Legs" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Arms" />
```

and everything should work.

Comment: I have added the code, for some reason its still force closing the app, I have added the code for view_stats.xml

Comment: i have edited the answer. As you can see the real problem was with your layout xml. Hope you didn't create DB from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I ended up completely rewriting this portion of the app, opting for a sleeker way of presenting the data, this problem was to do with my XML file though.