# Android SQLite How to format data?

Tags: android, sql, xml, sqlite

Currently I have a TextView that gets populated with a data String from my SQLite database, but its not very pretty to look at.

Currently the data looks like:

1 data1 data2 data3 data4 < all on the same line with whatever formatting is afforded to the TextView.

How do you format this kind of data in Android? Up to now I have only seen examples using list view.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Weight" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Waist" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Chest" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Legs" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Arms" />
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDBInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="info from db" />
    </TableLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

The XML where the database information is displayed is shown below:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDBInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="info from db" />
```

There just doesn't seem to be much in the way of specifying column widths, that sort of thing, seeing as the SQLite output is pretty much just a String output

Comment: post your code showing what have you done so far

Comment: @StinePike the java or the xml? the java can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439807/android-sqlite-added-extra-columns-now-cant-view-data) and the xml is simply a TextView

Comment: code where you are formatting.. also explain what kind of formatting do you want

Comment: @StinePike I have added the XML